# AsyncTask: how to add check on internet connection faults?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, connection, timeout, offline

i created the following activity that includes an AsyncTask to download JSON data from a remote url. I added an AlertDialog to check if the internet connection is available on the user's device and i added a timeout to handle slow internet connection.

Here is my activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_acitivity);

    if (isNetworkAvailable(this))
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("No internet connection");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });     
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();  
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        RelativeLayout progress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progress = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressBarlayout);
            progress.setOnClickListener(null);
            progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            int timeout = 120;
            String jsonString = null;

            BasicHttcat1arams basicParams = new BasicHttcat1arams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(basicParams, timeout * 1000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(basicParams, timeout * 1000 );
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(basicParams);

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://www.example.com/data.json");
            request.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.acat1end(line);
                }

                jsonString = sb.toString();

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return jsonString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

            JSONObject json;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(s);
                p1 = Double.parseDouble(json.getJSONObject("cat1").getJSONObject("subcat1").getString("rcv"));
                p2 = Double.parseDouble(json.getJSONObject("cat2").getJSONObject("subcat1").getString("rcv"));              
                p3 = Double.parseDouble(json.getJSONObject("cat1").getJSONObject("subcat1").getString("avg"));
                p4 = Double.parseDouble(json.getJSONObject("cat2").getJSONObject("subcat1").getString("avg"));
                p5 = Double.parseDouble(json.getJSONObject("cat1").getJSONObject("subcat2").getString("status"));
                p6 = Double.parseDouble(json.getJSONObject("cat2").getJSONObject("subcat2").getString("status"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

It works but my app crashes if, for example, the remote url is not available or during downloading the network or wifi go offline.

Here is the LogCat:

```
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478): Process: com.myapp, PID: 23478
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:155)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at com.myapp.MyActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:377)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at com.myapp.MyActivity$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:1)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
03-02 15:00:22.466: E/AndroidRuntime(23478):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to handle these events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the **String s** is null before creating the JSON object in **onPostExecute**. If not null proceed with whatever you are doing, if null recheck internet connection and retry downloading or anything you want.

Comment: Do not try to show the alertDialog inside doInBackground. It would throw exception as it is not run on UI thread. Rather return null from doInBackground in case of any error and show the alertDialog in onPostExecute if s is null.

Comment: I add this `} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    noConnectionDialog();
   }` at the end of try-catch block in onPostExecute() and it worked! Could this be enough to handle connection problems? As you cann see i do not check `String s` if it is null

Comment: Yes it should be enough.. Exception class catches all.

Comment: Great! Both answer make me to get the solution... now how to accept the right answer? :(

Answer (score 2):

The concept is called Exceptions and exception handling. Having no Internet access is an exceptional situation and handling it is to enclose all such code into this:

```
try {
   // all your code which can throw an exception   
} catch (Exception e) { 
   // handler; e.g. show an error dialog
}
```

Comment: Wrap the code with this `        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StratusActivity.this); ...
`

Comment: Sorry i do not understand... what part of code i have to wrap and what is StatusActivity.this ?

Comment: All the code that runs in doInBackground wraps into `try { } catch { handler(); }`. And then, the handler wraps into `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { createDialogOrWhateverYouNeedToHandleTheExceptionInUI();
} }` code. When creating a dialog, you need to provide the context. In your case it will be MyActivity.this.